# sshpass with SSH works, but sshpass with SCP doesn't

Tags: ssh, password, scp

In my case, I have a situation that I'm trying to send a file via SCP using sshpass
but I can't. I need to use a script with a password but the easiest way doesn't work

on the hostName2 I have no possibility to see configuration sshd_config etc. and send ssh-copy-id, I need use 'myPass'

look at this:

```
sshpass -p 'myPass' ssh -p 2122 tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

> ^ OK

```
sshpass -p 'myPass' scp ~/myDir/testPB.txt tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/chroot/tomcat/testPB
```

> ^NOT OK

**It works fine:**

```
[tomcat@hostName .ssh]$ sshpass -p 'myPass' ssh -p 2122 tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
Last login: Mon Aug 22 11:41:32 2016 from xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
#################
# hostName2 #
#################

JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
TOMCAT_HOME = /chroot/tomcat
LOG = /log/tomcat , /log/apache
LOG_ARCH = /log/arch/tomcat , /log/arch/apache
STATS = /log/stats
```

**and there is a problem:**

```
[tomcat@hostName .ssh]$ sshpass -p 'myPass' scp -vvv ~/myDir/testPB.txt tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/chroot/tomcat/testPB
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 195.182.52.175, user tomcat, command scp -v -t /chroot/tomcat/testPB
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Does the remote file exists? `sshpass -p 'myPass' ssh tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx ls /chroot/tomcat/testPB`

Comment: exists ;) the reason was different !
thanks for Your interest. 

solved

Comment: I vote against closing, problem is reproductible, (missing alternate port option in scp).

Comment: I cast a VTC under the "...or went away when a typo was fixed" umbrella. Good eyes spotting the difference in ports between the two commands!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You use an alternative port with `ssh -p 2122` but not with `scp`.

Try

```
sshpass -p 'myPass' scp -P 2122 ~/myDir/testPB.txt tomcat@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/chroot/tomcat/testPB
```

Please note upper case <kbd>P</kbd>.

As per [`man scp`](https://ss64.com/bash/scp.html):

> `-P port`
>
>   Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host. 
>   Note that this option is written with a capital ‘P’,
>   because
>   **`-p`**
>   is already reserved for preserving the times and
>   modes of the file in rcp(1).

Comment: It works! Great!
i appreciate that, thanks for help